# Powershell Closes Instantly

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I've looked all of the the internet and I cannot find any information that applies to this situation.

Powershell closes immediately upon starting. When I run it in Command Prompt I get the following:

```
Windows PowerShell terminated with the following error:
 Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.String[]'.
```

I have checked the following folders and no profiles exist:

> c:\users\me\appdata\microsoft\windows\powershell
>
> c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\
>
> c:\windows\systwow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\

I have tried to run with the following commands and have no luck:

`powershell -noexit`

`powershell -noprofile`

I have run the following commands and have no luck:

`sfc.exe /scannow`

`DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`

I also have gone to Control Panel -> Uninstall a Program -> Turn Windows features on or off then,
Removed Powershell, rebooted, then re-installed it.

After doing all of these steps I still am not able to run Powershell. ISE does not work either.

Comment: [1] does the ISE work? [2] can you run a simple script in the console? [3] there is no `-NoClose` parameter for `powershell.exe`. there is a `-NoExit` parameter, tho. [*grin*]

Comment: I have updated it to answer those questions. -NoExit is what I meant to say, good catch. ISE does not work.

Comment: You also, cannot uninstall Powershell on Windows. That feature is for PowerShell v2. Which really should be disabled these days, based on all MS announcements. If you are on Win 10, the PSVersion is v4 - 5x. If you installed PowerShell v7 (Powershell Core) You can install and uninstall that at will. However, Windows PowerShell is part of the OS. Do you have a restore point that you can go back to were it was working?

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to Powershell logging settings. I had the exact same issue after implementing Powershell Module logging using the wrong path for `ModuleNames`.

Check the values set in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ModuleLogging`

In my case, I made the mistake of adding a value of `ModuleNames` set to `*` - not realizing it should be a KEY named `ModuleNames` - which resulted in an error

> ```
> Windows PowerShell terminated with the following error:
> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.String[]'.
> ```

By adding the right path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ModuleLogging\ModuleNames\` with a `REG_SZ` value named `*` and with a value of `*` I got Powershell working again.

[image: Registry image]

Note that if this setting comes from a GPO (Group Policy Object) in the domain, it will need to be fixed there, rather than in the registry. Otherwise, the GPO will just overwrite the local settings the next time it applies.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run powershell, it loads the default modules present in the Modules directory. One of these modules (most likely a custom one you wrote) is causing errors and not allowing you to start.

Without knowing anything about the modules you have present in the directory located at: C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules, it would be hard for anyone to tell you the solution.

**Recommendation**

Remove any custom modules you have in there and add each module you need one at a time to see which one breaks your powershell.exe.  You will need to check each path you have defined for custom modules to be loaded as well.

Other way would be to clear out the PSModulePath from Environment variables and add one location at a time until you see which `Modules` directory is causing error.

**NOTE**: Write down the paths on a notepad somewhere before you clear it.

From the error it seems like a .net library class (dll) that is not correctly written.

Comment: I have no custom modules.

Comment: Clear out the PSModulePath from your system's environment variable and try to run powreshell.exe and see if that works. Write down the value to be able to revert back

Comment: Is there a way to completely rip out Powershell and re-insert it?

Comment: Remove the latest .net framework updates that you can and re-install them. Besides that there isnt much that I can think of.

Comment: You cannot completely remove and reinstall Windows PowerShell as I've noted above. Unless it was a version upgrade (a .Net upgrade that Jawad is hinting at) from v3 - v5x that you manually installed or as noted if it was PowerShell Core, which you can install side-by-side with legacy Windows PowerShell.